# Devise before_filter authenticate not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a model named Member which is database_authenticatable. However when I use:

```
before_filter :authenticate_member!
```

in a controller I get an undefined method error.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: After adding devise gem, did you bundle install and restarted your rails server?

Comment: Yes. Still having issues after bundling and restarting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason, I needed to run

```
rails g devise member
```

again to solve the problem.